# What Base image to get OpenJdk and Selenium to work

Tags: java, docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker file so that I can run OpenJDK 15 and Seleium driver with Chromedriver. Does anyone have an example or know the base image to use?

Comment: What's wrong with the existing selenium standalone/grid images? What issues are you running into?

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer I am just starting off with getting this project off the ground. Do any standalone/grid images support OpenJDK 15?

Comment: You can use RemoteWebDriver in any Java image with those containers. Do you have any requirements to use only one container?